# ¿Es posible crear una constante de clase al heredar en Java?

Tags: java, reflexión

Tengo una **clase que es abstracta** con un par de **métodos abstractos** y necesito que todas las clases que hereden de está tengan un campo *final static String* el cual contenga el nombre 'simple' de la clase hija, llamado TAG. Lo he estado intentado de varias maneras, pero todas me impiden compilar.

¿Es posible hacerlo? Y si es así, ¿Cómo se hace?

De manera que me funcione, pero no deseada lo tengo realizado como campo de la instancia.

```
abstract class A{

    protected final String TAG;

    public A() {
        TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
    }
}
```

Quiero obtener desde la clase hija el TAG como si fuera de la clase, no de la instancia, así:

```
class B extends A {
    public void mostrar() {
        System.out.println(B.TAG);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tu pregunta, **SI**, es posible tener una constante dinámica como tu necesitas, [aqui puedes ver una discusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936684/getting-the-class-name-from-a-static-method-in-java) (en ingles)

---

Respondido esto, en mi opinion, creo que no necesitas una constante para tu proposito, basicamente porque te complicaras la vida ya que tienes una clase abstracta, una constante final y clases heredadas...

Te propongo 2 alternativas (mira como consigo el `getSimpleName()` en los dos casos si quieres hacer variaciones)

---

## Metodo 1 (heredando, con metodo, no estáticamente)

```
public abstract class Q {
    public void mostrar() {
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
}
```

Tomemos 2 clases de ejemplo:

```
public class SubQ extends Q {
}
```

```
public class OtraQ extends Q {
}
```

Y un main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SubQ sq = new SubQ();
    sq.mostrar();
    
    OtraQ oq = new OtraQ();
    oq.mostrar();
}
```

**SALIDA:**

```
SubQ
OtraQ
```

---

## Metodo 2 (heredando, sin metodo, estáticamente)

Teniendo una estructura de clases como la tuya, sin metodo ni constante puedes directamente tener los datos que quieres asi:

```
System.out.println(Q.class.getSimpleName());
System.out.println(SubQ.class.getSimpleName());
System.out.println(OtraQ.class.getSimpleName());
```

**SALIDA:**

```
Q
SubQ
OtraQ
```

Answer (score -1):

La forma de realizar lo que deseas puede ser mediante herencia, creando un método el cual obtiene el nombre de la clase:

```
abstract class ClassA{


    public void mostrar() {
        System.out.println("Simple name: " + getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
}

class ClassB extends ClassA {

}

class ClassX extends ClassA {

}


public class myApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassB b = new ClassB();
        b.mostrar();     
        ClassX x = new ClassX();
        x.mostrar();   
    }

}
```

Teniendo como salida:

```
Simple name: ClassB
Simple name: ClassX
```

Comment: esto no le va a servir de nada, asignas el atributo en la superclase abstracta, por lo que, 1) cualquier clase que extienda y llame a `getTag()` siempre devolvera `A` y 2) nunca podrás volverlo a asignar en las subclases...

Comment: Hola @JordiCastilla. Pensé que lo que deseaba era obtener el nombre de la clase padre, pero ya veo ahora " obtener desde la clase hija el TAG como si fuera de la clase, no de la instancia"...

Comment: ¿para que has puesto la constante `TAG`? Queda bonita ahi, pero si no la usas...